# How do i insert random string into a table that is relevant to my project of a music library?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using SQLite and Python but i want to insert random string that is relevant for example if i wanted a certain song genre, i want song titles that arent random letters. I'd appreciate any help...

```
def genre():
genre=('''What genre do you want
1.
2.
3.
''')
choice=input(genre)

'''GENERATE RANDOM SONGS BASED ON GENRE INTO PLAYLIST DATABASE'''

def length():
length=input("How long do you want the playlist to last")

'''INSERT DATA INTO PLAYLIST WHICH ADDS TO USER LENGTH'''
```

Comment: This is just part of the code

Comment: Maybe query song titles, break the words apart on each space, then push those words into your playlist database?

Comment: @Hunter can you show me what u mean? i'm a noob at python and i want to learn from the pros like u

Comment: At this point I would probably work on python fundamentals for you https://www.learnpython.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query the song titles, break the words apart on each space, then push those words into your playlist database in SQLlite, and then do another for loop to retrieve those words from your database in a random order. 
            pseudo code

```
   --query the song
   --break string into separate words
   --push each word into a list
   --for loop that iterates over your list and sends each new word to your 
     database
   --then a function that will retrieve those songs from your database 
   --then present them to the user.
```

I would learn the fundamentals first and go through the examples.
Those are the steps you would need though, many separate functions. https://www.learnpython.org my friend
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/
for actually getting the information from a url.